# How to use animated splash screen for iPhone web app?

Tags: iphone, web, screen, animated, splash-screen

I'm creating a web app for the iPhone, and I've made a splash screen for it.  I'd like to have an animated loading symbol (like this one [image]) on the bottom of the splash screen.  I made an animated gif with it, but the web app only shows the first image in the gif.  How can I have an animated splash screen?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not actually seeing an animated splash screen. These apps just do additional loading stuff after the initial load, and display a view with an animation while they do so.

Comment: I was patiently waiting until the question was loaded `:P`

Comment: @Caleb, are you talking about an iOS native app or a mobile safari web app?

Comment: @Black Frog, Mobile Safari app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real splash can be only a static PNG image, however what you can do is defer all loading of heavy resources for later and in the beginning load only a view that has the same image as the splash but with a spinning wheel in the bottom of the view.

Then you can start loading the rest of the application while this view is animating and informing the user of the progress.

Comment: Thanks for the (almost) instant answer!

Comment: Looks like I can accept your answer in 8 minutes (don't ask me why)... :)